# How can I prove a DFA accepts a certain mininum number of states?

Tags: logic, proof-writing, automata

We know that if there are two languages, $L_1$ and $L_2$, if $L_1$ and $L_2$ are regular, the intersection of those two is also regular. Suppose we have two machines, $M_1$ and $M_2$, and using them, a new machine $M_3$ is built. If $M_1$ had $k>0$ states and $M_2$ had $l>0$ states, the new machine has to have $kl$ states at minimum.

How would I go about trying to prove this? I've been stuck on this for quite some time. I know that we would have to construct the languages $L_1$ and $L_2$ so that $M_1$ and $M_2$ accept them, respectively, which in turn allows the smallest machine accepts $L_1$ intersects $L_2$ has $k \times l$ states.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I assume $M_i$ is supposed to recognize $L_i$ and that $L_3 = L_1 \cap L_2$. If so, then the statement is not true. Consider the case that $L_1 = L_2$ and $M_1 = M_2$. Then we can take $M_3 = M_1$.

Comment: There is a general technique for finding a lower bound on the number of states a FSM recognizing a given language $L$, but it requires a little algebraic number theory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm wondering whether maybe you got the question the wrong way round, and what you're actually supposed to show is that you need *at most* $kl$ states.  Because that is true, whereas what you have asked about is not, as Qiaochu already mentioned in the comments (if $L_1$ and $L_2$ are the same language, then $L_1\cap L_2 = L_i$ for $i=1,2$ and so you can use either $M_1$ or $M_2$ to recognise the intersection, so you only need $\min\{k,l\}$ states in that case).

Let me know if you'd like an explanation of why you need at most $kl$ states, but you might find you can do the question once you realise what it actually says.